# Error on accessing iteritems() of an imported variable

Tags: python, import, jython, pydev

I'm using Jython if that's relevant.

util.py:

```
globals = {}
#...
globals["foo"] = "bar"
globals["baz"] = "qux"
```

main.py:

```
import util
for key, value in util.globals.iteritems():
    print "Key: %s, Value: %s" % (key, value)
```

My IDE (PyDev) underlines only 'iteritems' and tells me `Undefined variable from import: iteritems`

Yet the program runs and works as I expect it to.

I also get unresolved import errors on every `from x import y` that I do, and all of those imports work fine when I run the program too. Not sure if this is related.

Comment: try naming it something different than `globals`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It thinks you're taking about [org.python.util](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/package-tree.html) (or, a less likely possibility,  [distutils.util](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.util)) because the modules have the same name, and it knows those imports don't exist there.

You also shouldn't ever use the name `globals` because there is a builtin called `globals()`.

Rename the module and the variable and you shouldn't have a problem.